# How to protect non-metallic cable parallel to face of joist in attic?

Tags: electrical, wiring, attic

I would like to run non-metallic cable (Romex) along the sides of the floor joists in my attic.  Code (NEC 300.4(D)) says that wires need to be 1.25" from the top or bottom of the framing member.  With my 2x4 joists, this gets me one cable on a face.  What are my options to run more than one cable on a side (i.e. protect the cable because I cannot maintain the 1.25" requirement)?  Code mentions steel plates, sleeves, "or equivalent," but I don't know what I'm supposed to look for.  AC cable doesn't seem to provide the adequate protection that Code requires, either (correct?).  Are there exceptions for attics?  I'm going to fill the attic (eventually) with about 16-18" of blown insulation, and there won't be decking where I'm running my cables.

Comment: My aversion to rodent-wire-fires and my distrust that any building can ever really be rodent-free is why there's a network of EMT supported about 2" above my eventual insulation height in my attic. But I'm considered a weirdo on that front around here.

Comment: Are you going on top of the joists, through the joists, or along the face of the joists?

Comment: @Tester101 I'm going along the side face of the joists.  So, for a 2x4, it would be the 4" side.

Comment: Is the attic accessible via a fixed ladder or staircase?

Comment: It's got one of those pull-down ladders that folds back into the ceiling when not in use. (Aside, since you asked: I couldn't find a definitive Code answer as whether this is considered a "fixed" ladder.)  The attic itself is not really suitable for storage.  I can't stand up under the ridge joist, and the pitch is about 4-in-12, so about 3' on either side of the ladder, the rafters are under 39" from the floor joists.

Comment: @the_meter413 The ladder is part of the home, therfore it is "fixed".

Comment: @the_meter413 As far as National Electrical Code is concerned, if there's a staircase or a  fixed ladder the attic is accessible.  It has nothing to do with how much space there is up there, or how comfortably you can move around.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cable stackers I think:
[image]